# Variable Variable in django template

Tags: python, django, variable-variables

**view.py**

```
variable = 'amount'
amount = 200
print(variable) #actual: 'amount' expected: 200
```

In such case, is it possible to use Variable Variable like PHP?
in php, I could do

```
$variable = 'amount';
$amount = 200;
echo $$variable;
```

I know it might be not a good practice, but sometimes it could provide very powerful features.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean `Variable Variable`. But if you want to use string to create variable then use dictionary - `name = 'John'` `variable[name] =  name`

Comment: you could use a dictionary: `my_vars = {"name": "John", ...}` with as many keys as you want/need, and access it with `my_vars[variable_name]`

Comment: it's the concept of using variable as variable name, in this case $$variable_name will be John

Comment: use dictionary. It is prefered method.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Sayse I am switching from PHP to python, so I want to see if that's possible in python.

Comment: Thats a broad statement, different languages quite often have different ways of handling issues

Answer (score 1):

Neither Python nor Django's [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/) support [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)... fortunately. It's a confusing language feature in PHP and we're better off without it - as you said, it's not even a [good practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154588/are-there-any-good-use-cases-for-variable-variables) to use them.

Think of it as a bad habit in PHP that you'll be leaving behind now, even in PHP there are always better alternatives. Maybe someone thought it was a good idea at the time but modern best practices indicate otherwise.

If you feel the need for dynamic behaviour regarding variable *names* consider using a dictionary instead, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) for details.

Comment: so, using List is the only way out?

Comment: More like, dictionaries.

Comment: The OP is asking about Django Templates which is presumably django template language, not python

Comment: @Sayse Variable variables are also not supported in the Django templating language, as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/). I'd be surprised if it did, it'd go against the consistency with the Python language found in Django.